# How To Send NSData with AFNetworking 3 Without Using AFMultipartFormData

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking-3

I am trying to send wav file as a NSData to rest service with AFNetworking 3. I figured out how to send with AFMultipartFromData but i got an error like that
 `errorMessage = "Can Not Map Content-Type String multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+02588C5 To Media Type ";`

When i spoke with the guy who created rest service then he told me i have to send just NSData not anything like AFMultipartFormData. I need some help here because i could not find any way to send "just" NSData.
My code is below;

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxMyService"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"xx": @"yy ; zz"};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager2 = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL sessionConfiguration:configuration];
manager2.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

//I converted wav file to NSData
NSData *data=[self setVoiceRecordToNSData];



[manager2 POST:@"http://xxxMyService" parameters:nil
 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
{  
[formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"data" fileName:@"Path.wav" mimeType:@"audio/wav"];
}  
progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject 
{ NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);} 

failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code before POST

```
manager2.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"multipart/form-data"];
```